# «За» или «против». Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: кавычки

Аргументация «за» или «против» какого-либо шага...
Нужны ли кавычки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужны, если эти слова употреблены в значении предлога.

Кавычки вокруг (одного) слова обычно ставятся:

- слово используется нестандартно ("вкусный" ответ - интересный);

- названия (ресторан "Надежда");

- примеры чего-то (слово "за", предлог "против").

Примеры из книг:

`На самом деле, аргументация за и против расширения или ограничения сферы гражданского общества...`

`Аргументация за и против усреднения этих расчетов выходит за пределы изложенной методики и не может дискутироваться в настоящей статье.`

`Аргументация за и против функциональных методов в экономической теории, в том числе плюралистического отношения к причинности, осознания стратификации и сравнимости.`

`Вся аргументация за и против должна звучать при обсуждении этого вопроса в стенах Государственной Думы.`

Но если эти слова используются как название **традиционной** аргументации, после которых обычно нет продолжения контекста, то в кавычках.

Примеры из книг:

`Неоднократно подгонялась аргументация "за" и "против".`

`Если вынести за скобки чисто политический аспект, есть ли серьезная экономическая аргументация "за" и "против", нужно ли стремиться удержать их во что бы то ни стало или можно найти какие-то другие пути.`

Вот хороший пример:

`Так противоречиво выглядит традиционная аргументация "за" и "против" профессиональных армий, которая отражает наиболее устоявшиеся взгляды на преимущества и недостатки армии комплектуемой добровольцами.`

Здесь данные слова используются как название **традиционной** аргументации.

Answer (score 2):

Кавычки не нужны в выражениях ***голосовать за или против***, ***взвесить все за и против,*** так как слова ***за*** и ***против*** употреблены в значении **наречия или существительного.**

***Аргументация за и против какого-либо шага.*** Здесь слова ***за*** и ***против*** употреблены в значении предлога.

1) Вопрос № 211321

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, в словосочетании «взвесить все за и против» **нужно ли брать в кавычки** «за» и «против»?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

**Кавычки не нужны.**

2) **Орфографический словарь**

за1, **предлог**

за2, **в знач. сущ**. (взвесить все за и против), нареч. (голосовать за), сказ. (я – за, а он против).